# Get NorthWest and SouthEast of a map with Angular google maps (AGM)

Tags: google-maps, angular-google-maps

Now Angular google maps gives us `boundsChange` event, That event is triggered each time the boundary of the map is changed. If we said that the boundary is a rectangle or a box, then I will need 4 points to represent that box. the event gives us only the NorthEast and SouthWest points, How should I get the other two points?

```
<agm-map #map  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
    [zoom]="zoom" [mapTypeId]="mapTypeId" (boundsChange)="onBoundsChange($event)" [fitBounds]="true">
</agm-map>
```

```
onBoundsChange(bounds: LatLngBounds) {
 let NorthEst = bounds.getNorthEast().toJSON();
 let SouthWst = bounds.getSouthWest().tpJSON();
 // No Function to get NorthWest and SouthEast!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can conclude the other points from the given points this way:

```
let NorthWest: any = [bounds.getNorthEast().lng(), bounds.getSouthWest().lat()];
let SouthEst: any = [bounds.getSouthWest().lng(), bounds.getNorthEast().lat()];
```

it's a simple mathmatic trick, and it did the job.